# JSF EL expression does not work in required attribute of HtmlInputText

Tags: jsf, el

I am adding JSF components dynamically into an XHTML page created using JSF 1.2 with facelets. The required validation of some of these components have to be carried out only when a specfic button in the page is clicked.
So I've added the required attribute as an EL expression using the code:

```
String requiredExpression = "#{not empty param['form:button']}")
component.setValueExpression("required", 
                       createValueExpression(requiredExpression, String.class));
```

I have verified that the EL expression works by placing it in the required attribute of one of the static components in the page. I have also verified that the EL expression is getting added to the component by debugging the code. But it just does not work in the dynamic components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression must evaluate to a `boolean`, not a `String`.

Replace

```
createValueExpression(requiredExpression, String.class)
```

by

```
createValueExpression(requiredExpression, boolean.class)
```